# how to close current window after href to a download link

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have HTML code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    initPage(); // do someting

    location.href = "http://mail//download.php?lcaction=5" //download file link
    // window.open("http://mail//download.php?lcaction=5");

    // to close current window, but can not work
    window.opener = null;
    window.open("", "_self");
    window.close();
</script>
```

When I try to use `window.open` instead of `href`, it works in Chrome, but it fails in IE.

What can I do to make this work properly?

Comment: What errors/issues did you get/experience in IE?

Comment: in IE,the window close but the download link can not  touch off

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "touch off"?